# ERROR RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-layout, recyclerview

antes de nada comentaros que soy novato en programación, y estoy realizando mi proyecto de fin de grado superior, estoy implementando un chat con Firebase, y he conseguido llegar hasta el punto de tener las vistas creadas, con dos fragment con RecyclerView donde se visualizan los usuarios y las conversaciones realizadas, y luego una vista de la conversación.

Ya consigo seleccionar un usuario y mandar un mensaje, quedando guardado en firebase, el problema me surge a la hora de mostrar los mensajes en la vista, me dá el error del encabezado.

La aplicación no se sale, ni da ninguna excepción, simplemente graba el mensaje pero no lo muestra en la actividad.

ESTRUCTURA DE FIREBASE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

os adjunto mi código:

activity_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MessageActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundbienvenida">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenchat"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/btnchatsprinpress"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="username"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bar_layout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:background="#CDCDCD"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:id="@+id/text_send"
        android:background="@drawable/fondoeditextchatenviar"
        android:hint="Escribe un Mensaje..."
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingEnd="45dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:background="@drawable/btnchatenviaranima"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CLASS Chat

```
public class Chat {

private String sender;
private String receiver;
private String message;

public Chat(){}

public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.message = message;
}



public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getReceiver() {
    return receiver;
}

public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

ADAPTADOR

```
package com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Adaptadores;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat;
import com.example.luism.cordobasuma.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth; 
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.List;

public class MessageAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

private Context mContext;
private List<Chat> mChat;

FirebaseUser fuser;

public MessageAdapter (Context mContext,List<Chat> mChat){
    this.mChat = mChat;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) { 

    if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
        View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, 
false);
        return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left, parent, false);
        return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Chat chat = mChat.get(position);

    holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return mChat.size();}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView show_message;

    public ViewHolder (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        show_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (mChat.get(position).getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
        return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
    } else {
        return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
    }
}
}
```

ACTIVITY MENSAJE

```
package com.example.luism.cordobasuma;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Adaptadores.MessageAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView username;

FirebaseUser fuser;
DatabaseReference reference;

ImageButton btn_send;
EditText text_send;

MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
List<Chat> mchat;

RecyclerView recyclerView;

Intent intent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
 LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    //linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    //recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    btn_send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    text_send = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_send);


    intent = getIntent();
    final String userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");
    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msg = text_send.getText().toString();
            if (!msg.equals("")){
                sendMessage(fuser.getUid(),userid,msg);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this,"No puede enviar un 
mensaje vacío",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            text_send.setText("");
        }
    });


    reference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios").child(userid);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Usuario user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
            username.setText(user.getUsuario());

            readMessages(fuser.getUid(),userid);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message) {

    DatabaseReference reference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("remitente",sender);
    hashMap.put("receptor",receiver);
    hashMap.put("mensaje",message);

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
}

private void readMessages (final String myid, final String userid) {
    mchat = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mchat.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                if (chat.getReceiver() !=null && chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender() !=null && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                        chat.getReceiver() !=null && chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender() !=null && chat.getSender().equals(myid)) {
                    mchat.add(chat);
                }

                MessageAdapter messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this,mchat);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
}
```

ERROR:

```
2019-04-24 01:56:46.880 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma 
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token         android.os.BinderProxy@34ddeca
2019-04-24 01:56:47.464 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma     E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-04-24 01:56:55.874 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token     android.os.BinderProxy@2c59f01
2019-04-24 01:56:56.228 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-04-24 01:56:56.406 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-04-24 01:56:56.447 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.447 1604-1629/com.example.luism.cordobasuma I/ism.cordobasum: Background concurrent copying GC freed 26716(1689KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(208KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 860us total 285.248ms
2019-04-24 01:56:56.447 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.447 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.453 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.453 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.454 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.456 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.456 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.456 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.458 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.458 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.458 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.459 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.459 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.460 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.461 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.462 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.462 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.464 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.465 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.465 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.466 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.467 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.467 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.468 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.470 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.472 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.485 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.485 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.485 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.494 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.495 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.495 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.496 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.496 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.496 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.497 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.500 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.500 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.502 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.502 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.503 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.509 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.509 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.509 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.510 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.511 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.511 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.512 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.512 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.513 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.514 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.514 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.514 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.516 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.516 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.517 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.517 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.518 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.518 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.520 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.521 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.521 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.524 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.524 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.525 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.528 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.528 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for remitente found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.528 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mensaje found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
2019-04-24 01:56:56.529 1604-1604/com.example.luism.cordobasuma W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for receptor found on class com.example.luism.cordobasuma.Chat
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda`introducir el código aquí`

Comment: dentro de readmessages pone un breakpoint en el array y fijate si se va llenando con la data, puede que los parametros que le mandas en el readmessage no encuentren ningun valor en firebase por eso no te trae nada

Comment: Eso era Gastón, no encontraba los datos. Muchas Gracias